# magnifier box appears in middle of Emacs frame

Tags: frames

This box appears in the center of my Emacs frame with certain actions.

The most reliable way to trigger it is attempting to move the cursor past the boundaries of the buffer.

It disappears after switching to a different buffer, or scrolling enough to replace all the text in view.  Marking the area also solves it.

I don't think it's an accessibility feature because of the unusual way in which it disappears.  Anyone else recognize this?

Thank you!

My version:
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1404.13) of 2015-11-30

Installed with Macports on El Capitan

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that's the ding ding . . . bell bell -- Google a bit for **emacs ding bell** and you'll find several threads on the issue and how to turn it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug in Emacs, when running on El Capitan.

You can avoid this by setting `visual-bell` to nil (in which case Emacs beeps instead) or `ring-bell-function` to a function of your choice. If you want Emacs to be quiet, you can set it to `ignore`.

This has been fixed in the upcoming Emacs 25.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I thought I encountered it in Yosemite as well.  I was running Yosemite until last Wednesday.

Comment: I have never heard of anyone experiencing this in Yosemite. Pity you don't run it any more, it would have been good to know if this was the case, and, if so, to get a recipe for how to reproduce it.